# Google calendar api v3: How to retrieve the list of resources?

Tags: python-2.7, google-calendar-api

Google calendar resource 'calendars' had a [list()](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/resources/calendars/list) method in v1 , which has since been deprecated in v3. The alternative suggestion was to use [Google Apps Calendar Resource API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/calendar-resource/), which would soon be deprecated. What's a reliable way to retrieve a list of all resources such as all conference rooms in a company that a user has access to?

Answer (score 0):

If it is under Google Calendar API, use [`CalendarList()`](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList)

Check [**Overview of the Calendar API**](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/concepts/#calendar_vs_calendarList)

> [**Calendar**](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendars) — A calendar is a collection of events. Each calendar has associated metadata, such as calendar description or default calendar time zone. The metadata for a single calendar is represented by a Calendar resource. The **Calendars collection** contains Calendar resources for all existing calendars.
>
> [**Calendar List**](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList) — A list of all calendars on a user's calendar list in the Calendar UI. The metadata for a single calendar that appears on the calendar list is represented by a [**CalendarListEntry**](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList) resource. This metadata includes user-specific properties of the calendar, such as its color or notifications for new events. The **CalendarList collection** contains all CalendarListEntry resources for a given user. For a further explanation of the difference betweeen the Calendars and CalendarList collections, see [Calendar and Calendar List](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/concepts/events-calendars#calendar_and_calendar_list)

HTTP request

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList
```

---

But if you are talking about Admin SDK:

[image: image from Google]

Click the link [Calendar Resource](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/resources.calendars).

[`Resources.calendars: list`](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/resources.calendars/list)

> Retrieves a list of calendar resources for an account.

HTTP request

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/customer/customer/resources/calendars
```

Comment: "If it is under Google Calendar API, use CalendarList()" - Incorrect. CalendarList do not return a list similar to what OP is requesting. CalendarList returns any calendar, the user or service-account is subscribing to - by default, its own or none at all. If using a service account, this list will be empty. It makes no sense, to force a customer into diclosing the methods from within the Admin SDK to obtain a simple list of resource calendars, but it appears to be the **only** option left at this point.